# How to cut and paste columns with python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Original.xls')

#Delete columns
df.drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate','EmployeeID'], axis = 1, inplace=True)

#Renames Columns
df.rename(columns={'CheckNumber': 'W/E Date', 'CheckBranch': 
'Branch','DeductionAmount':'Amount'},inplace=True)


[['Branch','Deduction','CheckDate','W/E Date','SSN','LastName','FirstName','Amount','Agency','CaseNumber']]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Deductions Report.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Where I have the Branch, Deductions ...... that is the way I want the columns to be listed. Each column has specific information that I need to be kept with each column.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Try replacing that line with the following one:

```
df = df[['Branch','Deduction','CheckDate','W/E Date',
         'SSN','LastName','FirstName','Amount','Agency','CaseNumber']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Original.xls')

#Delete columns
df.drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate','EmployeeID'], axis = 1, inplace=True)

#Renames Columns
df.rename(columns={'CheckNumber': 'W/E Date', 'CheckBranch': 
'Branch','DeductionAmount':'Amount'},inplace=True)


df = df[['Branch','Deduction','CheckDate','W/E Date','SSN','LastName','FirstName','Amount','Agency','CaseNumber']]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Deductions Report.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```